# django choices form behaviour

Tags: python, django

i ve got a following strange issue in Django 1.4:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices = forms.ChoiceField()

# views.py
def my_view(request):
    vchoices = (('a', 'AAAA'),
               ('b', 'BBBB'),)

    form = MyForm()
# version1:
    form.my_choices=choices
# version2:
    form.my_choices.choices=vchoices

    context={'form': form}
    return render(request,index.html", {'form': form})
```

Considering the code above: 
If I use version1, I get the output rendered properly, although of course there are no choices in the choices box.
If I use version2, I get the following error:

> MyForm object has no attribute 'my_choices'

How can it be??? In version 1 the 'my_choices' attribute seems to be there, at least django does not complain.

The second question is:
If i set my forms.py the following way

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices = forms.ChoiceField()
    my_choices.choices=(('a','aaaa'),('b','bbbb'))
```

the form is rendered correctly and the dropdown box contains the choices.

Any idea how to explain this, or how to set the my_choices ' attribute choices in views.py ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In your version 2, it is looking for an "attribute", as against a "field" to apply choices against. The correct place to set the choices dynamically are in the `__init__`  method of the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form fields like `my_choices` do not become attributes on the form instances. Instead they become members of the `form.fields` dictionary. You can access it from `form.fields['my_choices']`.

However the normal way to do this is via the form's `__init__` method:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_choices'] = choices
```

and instantiate your form with `form = MyForm(choices=my_choices)`.

Comment: Okay thanks, but could you also explain the mechanism Django uses to hide the members: Actually I instantiate a class (MyForm) which inherits from forms.Form . This class has attributes like my_choices. How is it managed that these attributes become invisible??
What is wrong about 
form.fields['my_choices'].choices=((,),(,)) ?

Comment: It's not "hiding" the members, it's just that form fields, like model fields, are processed by the metaclass to translate that declarative syntax into instance-level attributes. For a full explanation you'll need to look at the code or see Marty Alchin's great book *Pro Django*.